# c++ current date and pointers problems!

Tags: c++, date, pointers, reference

in c++  ..

first of all I need to make a constructor  of class Date     d()  that creates the current date.. what should i do?

after that i have a problem with this program:

```
class Noleggio
{
 public:
  //Noleggio(unsigned f, unsigned n, unsigned c) : inizio() { film = f; copia = n; cliente = c; restituito = false; }
  bool restituito;
  unsigned addebito;
  //unsigned film, copia, cliente;
  Data inizio;
  Data restituzione;
  CopiaFilm* copia;
  Film* film;
  Cliente* cliente;
};

class VideoNoleggio
{
 public:
  VideoNoleggio (string n) : nome(n) {}
  void InserisciFilm (Film* f);
  void InserisciCliente (Cliente* c);
  void CreaCopiaFilm (string s, Film* f);
  void NoleggioCopia (unsigned n, Film* f, Cliente* c);
  void RestituzioneCopia (unsigned n, Film* f, unsigned t);
  int CercaFilm (Film* f) const;
  int CercaCliente (Cliente* c) const;
  int CercaUltimaCopia(Film* f) const;
  int CercaNoleggio (unsigned n, Film* f) const;
  string Nome() const { return nome; }
  unsigned NumeroFilm() const { return film.size(); }
  unsigned NumeroNoleggi() const { return noleggi.size(); }
  Film* QualeFilm (unsigned i) const { return noleggi[i].film; }
  string QualeTitolo (unsigned i) const { return film[i]->Titolo(); }
 private:
  string nome;

  vector<Noleggio> noleggi;
  vector<CopiaFilm> copie;
  vector<Film*> film;
  vector<Cliente*> clienti;
};
```

in function

```
void VideoNoleggio::RestituzioneCopia (unsigned n, Film* f, unsigned t)
{
 int i = CercaUltimaCopia(f);
 assert (copie[i].numero >= n  );
 assert ( !(noleggi[i].restituito) );
 Data d();
 int j = CercaNoleggio(n,f);
 assert ( d >= noleggi[j].inizio );
 noleggi[j].restituzione = d;
 noleggi[j].restituito = true;
 noleggi[j].addebito = t*( d - noleggi[j].inizio + 1 );
 // clienti[noleggi[j]->cliente]->Prelievo(noleggi[j]->addebito);
}
```

the compiler    returns an error here     `assert ( d >= noleggi[j].inizio )`    it seems to don't like   noleggi[j].inizio   as a good parameter...  (cause if i try  d >= d  it works--->  it's not an operator overloading problem i guess)

in data.h      `friend bool operator >= (const Data& d1, const Data& d2);`

any suggestion?

Comment: Strange - it was showing up as an unformatted mess on my screen, so I hit "edit" and then the "save" button - and it looks good right now.  I changed nothing.

Comment: I would translate the code here before posting. Better chances of getting a good answer.

Comment: @David Thornley. It looked unformatted here too. But it seemed to fix itself. Perhaps by your saving...

Comment: +1 for the class names, go Italia!

Answer (score 6):

The problem is the line

```
Data d();
```

This is interpreted as a function declaration (i.e. a function called `d`, taking no arguments and returning a `Data`).

Change it to

```
Data d;
```

or, if it's a POD structure and you want it value-initialised

```
Data d = Data();
```

As for how to implement the constructor, that will depend on your environment; there is no standard C++ date/time library. The most portable way is probably to use [Boost.Date_Time](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/doc/html/date_time.html), as daramarak suggests, but I've not used it myself so I can't do more than point you at the documentation. On Posix systems, you have the `time()` function to return the number of seconds since a defined date, and `ctime()` and related functions to break it down into years, months, etc. Windows probably has something similar, but I don't know about that.

Comment: ok that works!   but what if i want Data d    to be the current date? how do i have to define the constructor?

Answer (score 3):

My suggestion would be to use [boosts date time library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/doc/html/date_time.html)

Answer (score 2):

`Data d;` is the declaration of a `Data` object called `d`.

`Data d();` declares a function `d()` which returns a `Data`.

See [C++ FAQ 10.2](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors.html#faq-10.2).